# Переход на другую "страницу" с помощью кнопок в InlineKeyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть данный кусок кода, отвечающий за кнопки. При таком написании они отображаются все вместе. Как скрыть второй блок и сделать чтобы он появлялся при нажатии на кнопку "Следующая страница --->" и исчезал первый блок. Затем при нажатии на "<--- Предыдущая страница" скрывался второй и появлялся первый.

```
    elif call.data == 'animals':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Белка", callback_data='one')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Суслик", callback_data='two')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Лосось", callback_data='three')
        item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Кобра", callback_data='four')
        item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Следующая страница --->", callback_data='right_arrow')

        item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выдра", callback_data='six')
        item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Богомол", callback_data='seven')
        item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сыч", callback_data='eight')
        item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Воробей", callback_data='nine')               
        item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("<--- Предыдущая страница", callback_data='left_arrow')

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
        markup.add(item6, item7, item8, item9, item10)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите животное', reply_markup=markup)
```

Пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно за раз добавлять только 5 кнопок и реализовать обработчик нажатия кнопки `right_arrow`/`left_arrow` в котором вместо `bot.send_message` использовать `bot.edit_message_reply_markup` для изменения кнопок на следующие/предыдущие.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку!